# Problema para a exibição dos valores de um Array no front-end

Tags: php, array

Galera, boa noite. To com dificuldade para exibir os valores de um array no front-end. No backend ele aparece mas no front não.

Minha classe de tarefa service onde está a função que retorna o array:

```
 public function procurar(){

       global $procura;

       $comando = $this->conexao->prepare("select tarefa, id_status from tb_tarefas where tarefa like :nome");
       $comando->bindValue(':nome', "%{$procura}%");
       $comando->execute();

       $inf = $comando->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

       print_r($inf);

   }
```

Aqui está a parte do código responsável por dar o comando no banco na classe tarefaController :

```
elseif($acao == 'procurar'){

        $tarefa = new Tarefa();

        $conexao = new Conexao();

        $procura = isset($_POST['procura']) ? $_POST['procura'] : "";

        $tarefaService = new TarefaService($conexao, $tarefa);
        $retorno = $tarefaService->procurar();

        header('location: buscar_tarefas.php?resultado=1');
    }
```

E então lá no front-end eu abri o bloco de php e mandei escrever a variável $retorno. Dei também um require once para chamar a classe tarefaController:

```
<?php
 global $retorno;

print_r($retorno);
?>
```

Me ajudem por favor, galera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece é que você não está retornando nenhum valor na função procurar, então o valor de $retorno está como nulo.

Para resolver isso, você deve trocar `print_r($inf);` por `return $inf;`

[Confira a documentação!](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.returning-values.php)

Comment: Fiz o que você falou mas ainda assim não foi. Poderia dar uma olhada no projeto ? Caso isso não seja muito incômodo pra ti, segue o link no github. O projeto está em dois repositórios. github.com/gabrieltec97/Projeto-Help-Desk.git github.com/gabrieltec97/app_lista_tarefas.git

Comment: No seu código ainda está print_r($inf);, mude para return $inf e tente novamente. Faça o commit também.

Comment: E no seu Github também não achei onde você quer exibir o resultado

Comment: Tá comitado lá, irmão. Quero exibir lá no arquivo buscar_tarefas onde deixei um comentário lá. To tentando implementar uma busca naquele sistema, agora só falta exibir em tela. Dá uma olhada lá por favor

Comment: Remova o `header('location: buscar_tarefas.php?resultado=1');` de tarefaController.php:141

Comment: entao brother, se eu remover, ele não irá exibir naquela página. Quero que o conteúdo seja exibido nesta página chamada buscar_tarefas, pois essa página que faz a consulta no banco

Comment: Amigo, não é assim que se passa dados através de páginas em php.
O header apenas redireciona, e pelo que eu vi você não precisa dele pois o buscar_tarefas.php tem um require do mesmo.
Remova e faça a "consulta" através da pagina buscar_tarefas.php, ficaria assim:
buscar_tarefas.php?acao=procurar

Comment: Po nao to entendendo a forma que você ta falando mano, Pode alterar o código lá no github e salvar, se não der, pode me passar o código por aqui?

Comment: Já falei, só remover o header(); e fazer a requisição pela url buscar_tarefas ao invés de fazer em tarefaController

Comment: Funcionou, irmão. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela paciência em me ajudar. Valeu mesmo! tmj

Answer (score 0):

Se o processo das informações não forem feitas na mesma página em que você quer imprimir o resultado, você precisa transferir o retorno de uma pagina para outra.

Assim como o `@PauloVictor` falou, você precisa de um `return` na função primeiro.

```
public function procurar(){

    global $procura;

    $comando = $this->conexao->prepare("select tarefa, id_status from tb_tarefas where tarefa like :nome");
    $comando->bindValue(':nome', "%{$procura}%");
    $comando->execute();

    $inf = $comando->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $inf;

}
```

Depois de ter esse retorno, e caso os dados sejam processados na mesma página que será exibido o front, basta dar um `print_r()`que será imprimido, caso contrario, usar `session`, por exemplo, para passar as informações para outra página.

Comment: Fiz o que vocês comentaram, mas ainda assim não foi. Poderia dar uma olhada no projeto ? Caso isso não seja muito incômodo pra ti, segue o link no github. O projeto está em dois repositórios.  https://github.com/gabrieltec97/Projeto-Help-Desk.git https://github.com/gabrieltec97/app_lista_tarefas.git